# how to change a file name in Android Eclipse development

Tags: android, eclipse, filenames

I'm following this book, "Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours, 2nd Edition" from Sams publishing.

I'm at page 108, and it tells me to change the "main.xml" layout file to "splash.xml".
I try clicking on the file name in the package explorer, nothing. I also try right-clicking on the file name in the package explorer, and there is no option to rename the file. The only other way that comes to my mind is to change it in windows explorer. Do I have to change it in windows explorer, or is there a better way?

Comment: Right-click --> Refactor --> Rename

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try: right click -> refactor -> rename

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just select the file and press F2, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the file and press SHIFT + F6